# Change state of nested object props based on user input handleChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this component state

```
this.state = {
      title: "",
      salary: {
        min: "",
        max: "",
        single: ""
      }
}
```

I use this function for handling user input

```
handleInputChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]:e.target.value});
}
```

it works with

```
<input type="text" id="title" name="title" onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
```

Can I use such a function to change this.state.salary.min/max ...

I mean can this type of function work with nested objects in state and `<input/> name art`?

Comment: You're gonna have to give us a little more info, and maybe format the question a little better. What exactly isn't working? Could you provide an example?

Comment: i have state prop called `title` i  use this function and chnage the state based on  the name of the input field and its value , my  question is ... can  this type of logic work for nested objects in state (e.g. salary.min)

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, but you need to update whole nested object.

You have several options:

### Object.assign()

```
const salary = Object.assign({}, this.state.salary, { min: minValue });

this.setState({ salary });
```

### Spread operator

```
const salary =  {
    ...this.state.salary,
    min: minValue
}

this.setState({ salary });
```

### Immutable data structure

#### Immutable.js

```
this.state = {
    salary = Immutable.Map({ 
        min: 8,
        max: 10
    });
};

const salary = this.state.salary.set('min', minValue);

this.setState({ salary });
```

#### Immutability helper

See https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html

```
const salary = update(this.state.salary, {
    min: minValue
});

this.setState({ salary });
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that by using spread operator in setState.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    salary: {
        ...prevState.salary,
        min: newMinValue
    }
}))
```

Or, you can use Object.assign() if you are using ES5.

```
this.setState({
  salary: Object.assign({}, this.state.salary, {min: newMinValue})
});
```

Comment: No need to do `...prevState` since that's handled by React but yes, using the spread operator to copy the salary is correct.